# Google Maps Custom Style won't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infobox

I'm currently trying to customize Google Maps.

I styled my Map via the API (http://www.achimsagner.de/test/klysz/) but since I used the InfoBox my styles won't load. (http://www.achimsagner.de/test/gmaps_test.html)

I just can't find my mistake, maybe someone could help me.

Answer (score 2):

Add the styles to your myMapOptions

```
 var myMapOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: secheltLoc,
                styles : styles,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                scrollwheel: false          
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! Don't know how I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The page that applies the style contains these lines that aren't present on the page that doesn't:

```
  //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
    theMap.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    theMap.setMapTypeId('map_style');
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_styledMap_achimsagner_de_gmaps_testA.html)